# Fat volume not supported boot error on raspberry pi 4

Tags: boot

I got my first raspberry pi (pi 4, 8Gb model).
I am downloaded raspbian and Ubuntu from official website and flash them into my 32Gb Hp micro SDHC card (Class 10, U1).

I got an unexpected error "Fat volume not supported".
[image]
I checked the volume type on windows it is fat32.
I have also tried both the raspberry pi imager and balena Etcher.
And also verified the flash.
I have purchased the pi from robu.in website.
Why this problem arise? Any solution Please help me.

Comment: Do NOT post illegible pictures - post text.

Comment: consider using the latest tools and raspberry pi os image from
 https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/  Initial boot is supposed to convert and re-image from initial fat.  Interrupting that will cause issues.

Comment: @Abel what does `Initial boot is supposed to convert and re-image from initial fat` even mean?

Comment: @Abel - is that a thing that NOOBS does?

Comment: NOOBS is now old (favor their new imager) possibly too old for a new rpi4, but yes that is what it does - boots from an initial FAT and then re-images to your selected OS.  That process being interrupted can leave one with a bad card.